# C# Regex.Replace case insensitive as a function of the match

Tags: c#, regex

Say I have some text like this:

```
string text = "Hello world! hElLo world!";
```

I want to add a span tag around each of the words 'hello' in a case insensitive way so that the result is this:

```
string text = "<span>Hello</span> world! <span>hElLo</span> world!";
```

I tried to do this with Regex.Replace like so:

```
Regex.Replace(text, "hello", "<span>hello</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But what I really need is just the span tags to be created, leaving the original casing alone. So I would need the replace phrase to be a function of the matched phrase. How can I do this?

Comment: That's not `string.Replace`.

Comment: Sorry, just edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding the `hello` in the replacement pattern, use a `$&` backreference to the entire match value.

Replace `"<span>hello</span>"` with `"<span>$&</span>"`, use

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, "hello", "<span>$&</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

See more about replacement backreferences in [Substitutions in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: should be... replace "hello" with "<span>$&</span>"

Comment: @AgapwIesu He means replace `"<span>hello</span>"` with `"<span>$&</span>"` in the code, not literally use both in the `Replace` call.

Comment: Yes, `var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, "hello", "<span>$&</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: May I suggest that you add your last comment to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was ina rush. Added just now.